# is there a p-adic analogue to the surreal numbers?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, surreal-numbers

Because the p-adics are analogous to the reals, I was wondering if there was a structure that was analogous to the surreals in the same way, i.e this structure would have similar quirks/properties to the surreals except that a p-adic would be its base, not the real numbers.

Comment: The existence of "a surreal version of the p-adic numbers" is listed as an open question in the proceedings of a 2016 Oberwolfach workshop (Question $3$, page $3317$ of [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjky4Dtof_xAhXL0p4KHRrJCJsQFjARegQIGRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mfo.de%2Fdocument%2F1651c%2FOWR_2016_60.pdf&usg=AOvVaw25aciDXT-M0mCm8wYK_HYh)).

Comment: My guess would be "no" - as I understand it, the surreals depend pretty heavily on the *ordering* of the reals, i.e. by introducing an extraneous number $\epsilon$ that is "greater than zero but smaller than all positive reals". The p-adic numbers don't have any "well-behaved" ordering like the reals do, as far as I know.

Comment: The p-adic valuation is usually normalized on $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times$ so that it's a homomorphism into $\mathbb{Z}$. Maybe there's a way to extend the valuation to surreal numbers. It might be worth looking into the spherically complete field extension of the p-adics constructed by ultraproducts for some comparison.

Comment: It is common folklore (but I have never seen this result formalized) that there is no "natural" extension of the $p$-adic valuation to real, hence to surreal numbers.

Comment: The surreal numbers are the monster model of the theory of real-closed fields. So, there ought to be a monster model of the first-order theory of the p-adic numbers, whatever that is. Now, there is a famous theorem that the surreals are isomorphic to the proper class sized version of the hyperreals. So, I would guess that a proper class sized limit ultrapower of the p-adic numbers will do, and that elements in this field will have "infinite p-adic expansions" of proper class sized length.

Comment: I would also be relatively unsurprised if one could build such a thing using some variation of the surreal number "sign expansion" idea. The sign expansion of a surreal number is an ordinal length string of +'s and -'s. For any expansion of countable length, which is not eventually all +'s or all -'s, and which starts with +, we can view it as a real number by reading +'s until the first occurrence of (+-), treating the preceding string as the *unary* expansion of an integer, treating the (+-) as a decimal point, and then treating the string after as the binary expansion of the real.

Comment: It seems like there ought to be some simple or clever way to reinterpret these instead as 2-adic expansions extending infinitely to the left and only partly to the right. I wouldn't be surprised at all if some simple modification to the addition and multiplication rule for sign expansions were to somehow make this isomorphic to the 2-adic numbers, and then one can (similarly with the surreals) simply extend these sign expansions to arbitrary ordinal length to get... well, something interesting.

Comment: Lastly, another clue is that the p-adic numbers can all be viewed as subfields of the complex numbers with different topologies on them, and we already have a clear way to build the "surcomplex numbers." So, it seems like there are several fairly straightforward reasons why such a thing should at least exist, and perhaps some clear paths forward to building them.